# Install pgAgent on AWS RDS for Postgres

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, pgagent

Is it possible to enable/install pgAgent (job scheduler) for Postgres in AWS RDS?
I looked around and couldn't find anything on AWS documentation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

pgAgent is currently not available in the rds.extensions list and there is no ETA as to when it will be available.

If you want to run schedule jobs such as running DML/DDL statements then I will suggest using shell scripts (calling, for example 'psql' with the -c flag to execute a query) in conjunction with an OS level scheduler (e.g., crontab) on a Linux EC2 instance.

You can see currently supported extensions by below command:

```
postgres=> show rds.extensions ;
                                                                                                                                                           btree_gin,btree_gist,chkpass,citext,cube,dblink,dict_int,dict_xsyn,earthdistance,fuzzystrmatch,hstore,intagg,intarray,ip4r,isn,ltree,pgcrypto,pgrowlocks,pgstattuple,pg_buffercache,pg_prewarm,pg_stat_statements,pg_trgm,plcoffee,plls,plpe
rl,plpgsql,pltcl,plv8,postgis,postgis_tiger_geocoder,postgis_topology,postgres_fdw,sslinfo,tablefunc,test_parser,tsearch2,unaccent,uuid-ossp
```

Comment: I see. I would probably use Lambda with cloud watch to query my RDS instance and execute Postgres function on schedule. I am trying to schedule a Postgres function to run every 1 minute and updates some tables and stuff. thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Please mark my answer correct as it answered your question

Comment: Is this still a limitation in 2022?